# How to request facets from AWS CloudSearch via the PHP v2 SDK?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch, aws-php-sdk

I am using v2 of the PHP SDK for interfacing requests to AWS CloudSearch. T[he documentation is here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CloudSearchDomain.CloudSearchDomainClient.html#_search), however details and examples are somewhat lacking. I need to include facets in my search. It is clearly asking for a string but it is not clear exactly how the string should be formatted.

```
$cloudSearchDomainClient->serach([
    'filterQuery' => $filter,
    'query' => $query,
    'queryParser' => 'lucene',
    'facet' => '???'
]);
```

I have tried, for example:

```
'facet' => 'field1,field2,field3'

'facet' => 'facet.fieldname={sort:'count',size:5}'

'facet' => 'fieldname={sort:'count',size:5}'
```

(Some permutations based on examples in the [non-sdk request descriptions here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate syntax appears to be a string representing a javascript object.

For the default sort/count:

```
'facet' => '{fieldname:{}}'
```

To specify sorting options:

```
'faceet' => '{fieldname:{'sort':'count',size:5}}'
```

To request multiple facets:

```
'facet' => '{field1:{},field2"{}}"
```

Etc.